# git-p4 rebase running into conflicts

Tags: git, git-p4

I'm trying to convert from Perforce to git and have copied the Perforce repository with `git p4 clone //depot/path/to/project/...@all project` and `git push ssh://git@example.com:7999/project.git master`.

Now I want to keep the git repository in sync with the Perforce repository. Engineers only submit to the Perforce repository. When I:

```
$ git clone ssh://git@example.com:7999/project.git
$ cd project
$ git p4 sync //depot/path/to/project/...@all
$ git p4 rebase
```

it complains with a merge conflict. I don't understand why there should be a merge conflict since no changes should be happening in the git repository itself. What needs to be done to fix this?

Comment: I'm guessing it's unhappy about doing a `git p4 sync/rebase` against a normal `git clone`. I think it's designed to work against a `git p4 clone` only?

Answer (score 1):

Git p4 rebase is used to prepare submit from Git to Perforce. In your case you should not use it. Below is working for me to sync change from Perforce to Git.

```
git pull
git p4 sync
git merge -s recursive -X theirs refs/remotes/p4/master
git push origin master:master
```

Comment: As you note, the documentation for `git p4` says: "A common working pattern is to fetch the latest changes from the p4 depot and merge them with local uncommitted changes. Often, the p4 repository is the ultimate location for all code, thus a rebase workflow makes sense. [git p4 rebase] does `git p4 sync` followed by `git rebase` to **move local commits on top of updated p4 changes**." [emphasis added] Since the OP has no local commits, the rebase is not needed.

Comment: `theirs` is their repository name?

Comment: @SandraK it's a [merge strategy](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge--Xltoptiongt) [option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge-theirs).